# Accept on of two versions of a similar interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build stronger types for an interface that I currently can't change (too big a task). The interface should either allow `{a: string, x: number}` or `{b: string, x: number}` but not `{a: 'a', b: 'b', x: 1}`. My Typescript version is 3.9.2.

I already tried two different union types

```js
type IType = {a: string, b: never, x: number} | {a: never, b: string, x: number}
```

and for `{a: 'a', x: 1}` it keeps complaining about b missing and if I remove the `never` lines it says that `a` is not defined on the type.

I also tried the XOR helper type with no success.

Is there a way to get what I want? I currently have to resort to `{a?: string, b?: string, x: number}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to make those `never` properties optional:

```
type IType = {a: string, b?: never, x: number} | {a?: never, b: string, x: number}

const thing: IType = {a: 'a', x: 1};
const thing2: IType = {b: 'b', x: 1};
const thing3: IType = {a: 'a', b: 'b', x: 1}; // error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgKuaBeKBvAhgLigZ2AJwEsA7AcwBooAjAfm2IgDcJ9KAPegVwFsqWBfKAB806OlAbNW1bHiJl2XXgIBQKgMYB7YnijAAFiVLZ4iKCgzYA5OiuKoARn4BuDdt0GjAJhMJI5tCprKjsoDkcXNx1gPUMyAGZfMwssKBtQoLSQ%20ydnIA)

Be aware that this will allow you to do an explicit `undefined`:

```
const thing: IType = {a: 'a', x: 1, b: undefined}; // legal
```